# javascript update json value by list of keys

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an object which goes so deep. For example:

```
section: {
     data: {
          x = 4
     }
}
```

Real one is even more deep.

How can I update the x value when I have such a function:

```
const keys = [section, data, x];
const update = (newValue, keys) => {
      // it should be like this
      // myObjc[section][data][x] = newValue;
}
```

Comment: Did you try that? It looks like it should work

Comment: Aside from the object shown being invalid syntax... Does the function you show not work in some way?  Are you asking how to handle a scenario where the depth isn't known?  (In which case I'd write a loop of some sort to drill into the object properties, using the array you're already passing to the function.)

Comment: just uncomment. It will work. :)

Comment: I updated the question. The keys can change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

I think what you need is a deep set value function, like this

```js
const update = (newValue, keys, obj) => {
    for(const key of keys.slice(0,-1))
        obj=obj[key];
    obj[keys[keys.length-1]]=newValue
}
```

Comment: yes, you got it right. thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use a recursive function to avoid errors

```js
/**
 * Safely sets a key in an object or throws a predictable error
 * @param obj An object
 * @param path An Array of strings representing the path
 * @param value The new value
*/

function safeUpdateObject(obj, path, value){
  if(path.length === 0){
    throw new Error('Cannot update object with no path');
  }
  if(path.length === 1){
    obj[path[0]] = value;
    return;
  }
  if(path.length > 1){
    if(typeof obj[path[0]] === 'undefined'){
      obj[path[0]] = {};
    }
    if (typeof obj[path[0]] !== 'undefined' && typeof obj[path[0]] !== "object") {
      throw new Error('Cannot set key-value pair on non-object');
    }
    let unwrapped = obj[path[0]];
    safeUpdateObject(unwrapped, path.slice(1), value);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const o = {section: {data: {  x: 4 }} }

const keys = ['section', 'data', 'x'];
const update = (newValue, keys, obj) => {
      const l = keys.reduce((acc, x, i) => {
            if (i == keys.length - 1) {
                  acc[x] = newValue
            }
            return acc[x]
      }, obj)
      obj = l
}

update(5, keys, o)
```